# Creating lines from points pair coordinates with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, convert, geometry

I've got some points pair coordinates (start and end points) which I have to transform into lines. Until now, I used an append of both the coordinates in a `pippo.Point()`, a `pippo.CalculateGeometry()` to define the geometry of each piont, and `pippo.append(defined geometry)` to identify the pair of points, and then PointsToLine to obtain my line. This is quite time expensive to do for hundreds of lines.

Is there a shorter way to do this?

For example, place starting and ending point of each line in different fields of a single table and import lines directly without passing for points geometry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This reads a table (Excel sheet in this case, but could be any table type) that looks like so:

[image]

S_X is start X point, E_X end X point, same for Y's. We iterate through the input table, then for each row, set the start/end X/Ys into a point, add that point to an array, then create a polyline from the array of two points. Then insert into the featureclass. Rinse and repeat.

```
import arcpy

in_rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(r"D:\Temp\Lines.xls\Sheet1$")

point = arcpy.Point()
array = arcpy.Array()

featureList = []
cursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(r"D:\Temp\Lines.shp")
feat = cursor.newRow()

for in_row in in_rows:
    # Set X and Y for start and end points
    point.X = in_row.S_X
    point.Y = in_row.S_Y
    array.add(point)
    point.X = in_row.E_X
    point.Y = in_row.E_Y
    array.add(point)   
    # Create a Polyline object based on the array of points
    polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array)
    # Clear the array for future use
    array.removeAll()
    # Append to the list of Polyline objects
    featureList.append(polyline)
    # Insert the feature
    feat.shape = polyline
    cursor.insertRow(feat)
del feat
del cursor
```

And you get your lines:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and estimate duration of my analysis.. it was exactly what I was trying to do :-)

Comment: For the line point.X = in_row.S_X it returns an error saying that the input value is not numeric. I tried to make it int or float or even numeric but doesnt work because field is not a number is Nonetype. Any help?

Answer (score 5):

I created a python script last week (not using ArcPy though), that takes points that are creating the geometry of bus lines (a point shp) according a sequential number field ("SEQ"). You could easily tweak it to take the coordinate from a field of the same feature (using field value instead of geometry).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
###############################################################################
from sys import argv
import osgeo.ogr
import os, os.path
###############################################################################

script, srcSHP = argv

#-- Open source shapefile
shapefile = osgeo.ogr.Open(srcSHP)
layer = shapefile.GetLayer(0)
spatialRef = layer.GetSpatialRef()

#-- Output directory
outDir = os.path.dirname(srcSHP)
outDirName = os.path.basename(outDir)

driver = osgeo.ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
outFile = driver.CreateDataSource(os.path.join(outDir,outDirName + "_lines.shp"))
outLayer = outFile.CreateLayer("layer", spatialRef)

#-- Adding fields to the output shapefile
fieldDef = osgeo.ogr.FieldDefn("line_no", osgeo.ogr.OFTString)
fieldDef.SetWidth(12)
outLayer.CreateField(fieldDef)

fieldDef = osgeo.ogr.FieldDefn("From_SEQ", osgeo.ogr.OFTReal)
outLayer.CreateField(fieldDef)

fieldDef = osgeo.ogr.FieldDefn("To_SEQ", osgeo.ogr.OFTReal)
outLayer.CreateField(fieldDef)

#-- Going through each feature, one by one
#-- The last point is the end of the line so I don't want to iterate through that one
for i in range(layer.GetFeatureCount()-1):
    lString = osgeo.ogr.Geometry(osgeo.ogr.wkbLineString)  

    feature1 = layer.GetFeature(i)
    feature2 = layer.GetFeature(i+1)

    # When it's a new line, the sequential number restart to 1, so we don't want that line
    if feature1.GetField("SEQ") < feature2.GetField("SEQ"):
        geom1 = feature1.GetGeometryRef()
        geom2 = feature2.GetGeometryRef()

        geom1x = geom1.GetX()
        geom1y = geom1.GetY()
        geom2x = geom2.GetX()
        geom2y = geom2.GetY()

        lString.AddPoint(geom1x, geom1y)
        lString.AddPoint(geom2x, geom2y)     # Adding the destination point

        #-- Adding the information from the source file to the output
        feat = osgeo.ogr.Feature(outLayer.GetLayerDefn())
        feat.SetGeometry(lString)
        feat.SetField("line_no", feature1.GetField("line_no"))
        feat.SetField("From_SEQ", feature1.GetField("SEQ"))
        feat.SetField("To_SEQ", feature2.GetField("SEQ"))
        outLayer.CreateFeature(feat)

print "The End"
```

Each pair of point will create a single line.
There may be a more elegant way to do this, but it created 3900 lines in about 15 seconds so it works for me...

Comment: Thanks, looks exactly like massive elaboration.. that should be really useful to me. I'll try and then feedback.
thanks for now.

Answer (score 3):

you can use these these two tools [make XY event layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006z000000) and [Points to line](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003s000000), by seeing the paramaters needed in points to line ( line field , sort points) and update input table data, the task could be simpler

Answer (score 2):

this is just an update of @ChadCooper's answer, because "da" cursors are now advantageously replacing the previous cursors:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_table,[orig_namefield,x1,y1,x2,y2] ) as in_rows:
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(output_lines,["SHAPE@",name_field]) as cursor:
        for row in in_rows:
            # build array for line segment
            array = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(row[1],row[2]),arcpy.Point(row[3],row[4])])
            # Create a Polyline object based on the array of points
            polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array)
            # Insert the feature
            cursor.insertRow([polyline,row[0]])
```