# Validating data in ModelBuilder with TrackBuilder tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, geoprocessing, points-to-line

I have FGDB with points feature classes that I want to convert to lines using using a ready-made script called [TrackBuilder](http://coast.noaa.gov/digitalcoast/tools/track-builder). I am using model builder:

[image: Model]

When I populate the Track Builder script tool with the parameters everything looks fine. But when I validate the tool goes white

[image: Validated model]

WHY?

The beginning of the Track Builder script looks like this:

```py
import arcpy, os, sys, traceback, datetime, math, re

## Input Paramaters
sInputFile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
sID_Field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
sDT_Field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
sOutWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
sOutName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
sLineMethod = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5)
sMaxTimeMinutes = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6)
sMaxDistMiles = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)
sIntervalHours = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(8)
sAddVoyageData = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(9)
voyageTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(10)
voyageMethod = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(11)
sAddVesselData = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(12)
vesselTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(13)
```

---

According to the TrackBuilder instructions the input point should be a feature class containing a date field and an unique number for each ship.

Everything looks correct here:

[image]

The whole TrackBuilder script can be found [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24084358/TrackBuilderVersion2.py)

Comment: When a tool goes white during validation that is saying that one or more parameters are invalid. We can't tell from your screen shot. For example the iterator is passing out a FeatureClass but is your input requirement a FeatureLayer? You need to make your model, toolbox and code available to others if you want an answer to this question?

Comment: You are right. Already edited!

Comment: What happens when you create a simpler model with just the TrackBuilder tool and its inputs (no iterator)?  Will it validate and then run successfully?

Answer (score -1):

This is alternative way to convert point to line using arcpy:

[How to create lines from points pair coordinates with arcpy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34647/how-to-create-lines-from-points-pair-coordinates-with-arcpy)

Comment: Thanks! TrackBuilder script can segment the line according to time and distance which is useful for our analysis and the reason why we are using it.