# Iteration from a text file

Tags: arcpy, iterator

Trying to determine logic to create a line from the points for each Line_X number
Example: Create array of points, then a polyline for all points of Line_1, then Line_2, etc.

```
   pointList = arcpy.Array()
   coordinate = line.split(",")
   point = arcpy.Point(coordinate[0], coordinate[1])
   pointList.add(point)

Line_1, 529018.125025, 4108038.05548
Line_1, 529005.718792, 4108028.20659
Line_1, 528993.340503, 4108018.73931
Line_1, 528980.990158, 4108009.65364
Line_1, 528968.667757, 4108000.94958
Line_2, 528956.373301, 4107992.62713
Line_2, 528944.106788, 4107984.68629
Line_2, 528931.86822, 4107977.12705
Line_3, 528919.657595, 4107969.94943
Line_3, 528907.474915, 4107963.15341
Line_3, 528895.320179, 4107956.739
Line_3, 528883.193387, 4107950.7062
Line_4, 528871.09454, 4107945.055
Line_4, 528859.023636, 4107939.78542
Line_4, 528846.980676, 4107934.89744
Line_4, 528834.965661, 4107930.39107
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? I'm not sure I can follow how the output of your code snippet differs from what you expect it to do.

Comment: @Kersten - Sorry for the confusion. I want to create a pointList for all the coords associated with Line_1, then Line_2, etc.  From there I can create a polygon based on pointList for each Line_x.

Comment: Is this helpful?: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/34647/8104

Comment: @Aaron - I found that link during my search. My issue as a newbie is collecting all the points for the pointList array based on the Line Number. For example, I need a pointList for all values associated with Line_1, then a new pointList for Line_2 and so on.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.